# Drag and Drop both sides

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I want to make a DragAndDrop program for my project. I would like to a drag a picture from one picturebox to another and that's working pretty nice. But it won't go back to the orignal picturebox. I am working with 6 picturebox with 3 on first row and 3 on second row. I have drag the picturebox from first row to second and combine with the right description. Is it possible to make only 3 events (mouse_down, dragenter, dragdrop) and stil every picturebox will work because now I have to make 3 events for each picturebox and like this way i need 18 events.... Please help meeee

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        pictureBox2.AllowDrop = true;
        pictureBox3.AllowDrop = true;
        pictureBox4.AllowDrop = true;
        pictureBox5.AllowDrop = true;
        pictureBox6.AllowDrop = true;

        pictureBox1.MouseDown += MouseDown;
        pictureBox2.MouseDown += MouseDown;


        pictureBox1.DragEnter += pictureBox2_DragEnter;
        pictureBox1.DragDrop += pictureBox2_DragDrop;

        pictureBox2.DragEnter += pictureBox2_DragEnter;
        pictureBox2.DragDrop += pictureBox2_DragDrop;
    }

    /*private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }*/

    private void pictureBox2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
         e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void pictureBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
    }private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
        pictureBox2.Image = null;
    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
        pictureBox2.Image = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should utilize the `sender` object you get in those events.

Instead of setting the drag object to an image, I changed it to the PictureBox itself:

```
void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  DoDragDrop(sender, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Notice this isn't pictureBox1_MouseDown, but just pictureBox_MouseDown.  All of your PictureBox controls should wire their MouseDown events to this one method:

```
pictureBox1.MouseDown += pictureBox_MouseDown;
pictureBox2.MouseDown += pictureBox_MouseDown;
// etc...
```

You continue this process for the other events, too:

```
void pictureBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;  
}
```

For the DragDrop event, cast the dragged object back into a PictureBox control:

```
void pictureBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  PictureBox pb = e.Data.GetData(typeof(PictureBox)) as PictureBox;
  if (pb != null) {
    ((PictureBox)sender).Image = pb.Image;
    pb.Image = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added DragEnter, DragDrop and MouseDown event to every picturebox like (pictureBox1.MouseDown += pictureBox_MouseDown;). AllowDrop =true. used the code like you said but it's not working neither am I getting an error...

Comment: @user3612023 Can't see what you are doing differently.  Place debug breakers to see if the events are firing.